# GAM log link does not work without starting values

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, link-function

I am trying to estimate a GAM regression model using the implementation of `gam` from the `mgcv` package. I have a working Gaussian model for the dispersion and a log link for the linear predictors but I receive the error

```
>"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : cannot find valid starting values: please specify some".
```

**Edit 1** - The exact syntax is

```
splineWAR <- gam(WAR ~ s(zAge, bs="cr") + s(zAdjProd, bs="cr") + s(zSOPct, bs="cr") + s(zBBPct, bs="cr"), family=gaussian(link="log"), data = mydata,  start=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I have read the relevant threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567169/glm-function-in-r-with-log-link-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212063/r-glm-starting-values-not-accepted-log-link) but have unable to apply the steps suggested to a multiple regression. For instance, when I try and set start values for the 5 variables in my regression (1 dependent and 4 independent) by adding the `start=c(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)` argument (where the `n`'s are the mean of the relevant variable), I receive the same error even though I am seemingly copying the syntax exactly from the first link. Can anyone make a suggestion as to what I should try next? Thanks.

**Edit 2** The code in the `gam.fit` function that runs right before the error is -

```
if (!(validmu(mu) && valideta(eta))) 

stop("Can't find valid starting values: please specify some")
```

Comment: The five variables to supply starting values for do *not* include the dependent variable! (It's not multiplied by any parameter in the model, of course.) They should be the *constant* together with one for each of the four independent variables. Perhaps that is the cause of your problem? If you can, first run an *ordinary* regression of log(DV) against the IVs and then use the (five) coefficients from that as your start.  What happens?

Comment: As it turns out, I was not using the glm function but the gam function. When I run the glm function using the specification described in my question, the model runs as expected. However, when I switch back the gam function, I get the error I described. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Given that a GAM of this sort will have far more than 5 coefficients (there will be a column in the model matrix for each basis function that comprises each cubic regression spline), you aren't supplying enough starting values. How about you git the model without the `family`, save that fit as say `foo` and then refit your model with `start = coef(foo)`. The last bit might need `start = log(coef(foo))`...?

Comment: @whuber There's an intercept in the model, so that will be why it is working with 5 starting values in the GLM case.

Comment: @Gavin That was exactly my point: the question strongly suggests that the five values correspond to the *DV* plus four *IV*'s (and no intercept), which is not right. If you don't get the starting values to correspond with the proper variables, you can run into trouble... .

Comment: If I was using the wrong starting values, would I not receive an error about the values not converging as opposed to one that says that starting values cannot be found? Also, please keep in mind that I have tried using the mean value of the variable as well as a starting point but it does not make a difference.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I tried your suggestion but I receive the same error.

Comment: @zgall1 Yes, my reading of the mgcv:::gam.fit function suggests this should throw an error, and it does when I try it.

Comment: I think I understand @zgall1 Do you have any values in the response <= 0?

Comment: Yes I do. Is that the issue?

Comment: OK, I'm writing an Answer to explain. Give me 10 minutes

Comment: Re your Edit 2, did you debug that to see that it stopped there? There is a second place where that error occurs but you won't see it in the `gam.fit` code for reasons I am explaining in my Answer

Comment: @GavinSimpson I did not debug. I am actually not quite sure how to do that. I can definitely figure it out if I can find a link to instructions.

Comment: I've added an Answer now which I think explains things. This looks like a bug to me. I can email Simon Wood, author of **mgcv** and clarify for you if you'd like?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes that would be great.

Comment: @zgall1 Done - will follow up if anything comes of it.

Comment: Just to conclude this Q&A, Simon Wood has now fixed this bug in v 1.7-25 of his **mgcv** package following my bug report citing this Q&A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** Simon Wood has fixed this bug in **mgcv** in version 1.7-25. The entry reads:

```
* bugs fixed whereby etastart etc were not passed to initial.spg and
  get.null.coefs.
```

---

There are a number of places where an error message of the kind you show might be produced. The first is in the initialisation of the GAM:

```
> gaussian()$initialize
    expression({
        n <- rep.int(1, nobs)
        if (is.null(etastart) && is.null(start) && is.null(mustart) && 
            ((family$link == "inverse" && any(y == 0)) || (family$link == 
            "log" && any(y <= 0)))) 
        stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
    mustart <- y
})
```

Note the last clause there: `(family$link == "log" && any(y <= 0))`

The first part of the clause is `TRUE` in your case, what about the second part?  That will fail, but the question then is, why did it fail as `is.null(start)` should have been `FALSE` in your case. This code actually gets called in `gam.fit` through `mgcv:::estimate.gam` and thence `mgcv:::initial.spg` as shown by the `traceback()`:

```
> traceback()
6: stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
5: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
4: eval(family$initialize)
    3: initial.spg(G$X, G$y, G$w, G$family, G$S, G$off, G$L, G$lsp0)
2: estimate.gam(G, method, optimizer, control, in.out, scale, gamma, 
       ...)
1: gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat, family = gaussian(link = "log"), 
       start = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

If we look in `mgcv:::initial.spg` we note these lines (ignore the `nobs` one)

```
start <- etastart <- mustart <- NULL
nobs <- nrow(X)
eval(family$initialize)
```

i.e. the code above evaluates the expression I showed earlier. But it does so after scrubbing out `start`.

I think this is a bug here as I don't see how you can fit the model you want to with the way this is coded. For example, using

```
 library(mgcv)
 set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
 dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
 b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3), data=dat, start = 1:5)
```

we note that that fails but it tells us how many starting values to provide.

```
> b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3), data=dat, start = 1:5)
Error in gam.fit(G, family = G$family, control = control, gamma = gamma,  : 
  Length of start should equal 37 and correspond to initial coefs.
```

OK. change this to a `"log"` link and refit with 37 starting values

```
> b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat,
+          family = gaussian(link = "log"), start = runif(37))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  cannot find valid starting values: please specify some
```

and it still fails.

Once this problem gets fixed by the author, you'll still need to specify the correct starting values for the number of terms in your spline model.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer. I just tried re-scaling my y values from so that all y > 0 and it worked. Given what you wrote, I have no idea why but I'm glad to finally have made some progress.

Comment: In your case, the last clause `(family$link == "log" && any(y <= 0))` would evaluate to `FALSE` now that you rescaled the data and that would mean the entire set of clauses evaluates to `FALSE` and hence the error passes. This clearly seems like a bug so I'll email Simon and refer to this Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

An example of your syntax would be helpful.

GLMs require both a family (or what I call a variance family) and a link function to define the Fisher Scoring algorithm that solves for your parameter estimates. With Poisson variance and log link, this is Poisson regression or regression, attained with the argument `family=poisson` to `glm`. However, use the following argument `family=binomial(link="log")` and you get relative risk regression.

Most families in the `R` GLM function allow you to specify `link="log"` as an optional argument to the family object (e.g. `gaussian`, `gamma`, `poisson`). Irregular GLMs, especially ones for which the range of the link function is bigger than that of the fitted mean in the variance, have bizarre constrictions imposed on the parameter space which Fisher Scoring cannot accommodate.

Using the `traceback()` function is always useful with errors like these. You can also find the iteration where the algorithm diverges by specifying `glm.control=list(maxit=1)` for a 1 step estimator, `glm.control=list(maxit=2)` for a 2 step, and so on and so forth. Plotting your $\beta^{(i)}$ estimates for the (i)-th iteration will help you see what's happening before the Hessian becomes singular, Fisher Scoring diverges, and R explodes.

Your problem with starting values may be because you're supplying the means of the response variables when the variables are *contrasts* between the *logs* of the means. Hence ratios of logs of averages would be a better starting place. Personally, if this were such an issue, I'd fit a regular GLM to make sure the algorithm isn't universally divergent and use the parameter estimates for that model to start another.

For instance: Feeding forward logistic regression estimates (ORs) to obtain risk ratios (RRs)

```
## retrospective incidence of something nasty
data <- data.frame(cases=rpois(10, 10), controls=rpois(10, 1000), age=factor(seq(10), labels=c('0-10', '10-20', '20-30', '30-40', '40-50', '50-60', '60-70', '70-80', '80-90', '90-100')))

## logistic regression
fit <- glm(cbind(cases, controls) ~ age, data=data, family=binomial)

## relative risk regression
fit2 <- glm(cbind(cases, controls) ~ age, data=data, family=binomial(link='log'), start=coef(fit))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. In the comment to my question above, I mentioned that I made an error in my original question and was actually using the gam function instead of glm function. When I ran the help function on gam (http://127.0.0.1:29054/library/mgcv/html/gam.html), I noticed that there was no start parameter. This makes the error all the more confusing.

Comment: You can ignore my comment about it not having a start parameter. The gam.fit internal module does accept the start parameter. The synax I am using unsucessfully is splineWAR <- gam(WAR ~ s(zAge, bs="cr") + s(zAdjProd, bs="cr") + s(zSOPct, bs="cr") + s(zBBPct, bs="cr"), family=gaussian(link="log"), data = mydata,  start=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: This is most likely because you're using splines in your formula, which changes 1 variable into several (3 or more usually) in the model matrix. Alas, if they're adaptive smoothing splines, I'm certain of the necessary degrees of freedom. You can arbitrarily increase the number of zeros in the model. I cannot replicate the `s(x, bs)` since `s` only takes arguments `df` and `spar`. Setting `df` would probably let you know how many zeroes are necessary to start the algorithm.

Comment: @AdamO Whay would that matter. `mgcv:::gam()` is just a penalised GLM. Non-standard links may need good starting values, as you mention.

Comment: @AdamO Given the syntax used, I'm pretty sure this is `gam()` from package **mgcv**, not the same from package **gam**.

Comment: @GavinSimpson You are correct

Comment: I am following a tutorial to try and learn how to use the **mgcv** package and was unaware of the alternate **gam** package

Comment: @GavinSimpson using splines in the formula changes the model matrix. Examine the following `x <- rnorm(10)`. `model.matrix(~x)`, `model.matrix(~bs(x))`. While `~s(x)` doesn't resolve to anything different in the model matrix, it must be used in the `gam.fit` subroutine (with adaptive knots and DFs for the solver).

Comment: As I am new to the world of GAM regression, I am struggling to understand some of the terminology you are employing. To clarify - given what @GavinSimpson pointed out with regards to using a different gam() function, does your suggestion about arbitrarily increasing the number of zeros still apply? From what I can tell, it seems that the issue is not with the number of zeroes but with the syntax I am using.

Comment: @AdamO You edited your comment after I wrote mine. You are making the same point I tried to in comments on the other Answer and the Question.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I see now that `gam` is available in both the `mgcv` package and the `gam` package. Only the former implementation has the `s()` command for predictors such that `bs="cr"` can be applied as an argument. Thanks for clarifying that. It's important for reproducibility and  I edited the question.

Answer (score -2):

The parameter "start" takes values for the parameters not for the variables in the regression. The model only has 4 parameters (one for each dependent variables) so you should try start=c(0,0,0,0).

Comment: I have tried this as well but I get the same error.

Comment: No, this is not correct at all. Ignoring the spline aspect there are 5 terms in the model, the 4 variables named **plus** the model intercept or constant term. However, as this is a GAM with cubic splines, the actual number of terms in the model is a lot more because each spline is determined by a set of $k$ basis functions.